# SQL - How insert into one single table column a array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a personnal project and I would to register the data provided by the user.
The data looks like that :

```
$array = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

I would like to register this array in ONE SINGLE table column. I would like to do that (I know this request will not work):

```
INSERT INTO `test`(`user_data`) VALUES ($array)
```

What can I do in order to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: **No, no, no, no, no!** Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: if you want to do something like that change your array into string and then do it

Comment: @juergend Genuine question, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Andrew: It is slow, complicated to handle and against every DB normalization rule.

Comment: @juergen d: It seems to me that hp95 simply wants to insert 5 values in 5 rows of a table which consists of one column, whereas you are talking about storing an array in one field, i.e. one column in *one* row.

Comment: I would like to store in one row multiple values (the number of value is between 1 and 31). I don't want to have for a single user 31 rows :(

Comment: @hp95: Okay, this wasn't clear. You can do this. But keep in mind that the array should have no meaning to the database. You will never ask for single values of the array (e.g. whether the array contains a 3); it is just a string. You can use any representation for this, e.g. '1,2,3,4,5' or '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' or '1|2|3|4|5'. It doesn't matter, only stay consistent. If the array *does* have a meaning you want to query against, then I am completely with juergen d here.

Comment: My idea was to store the array into the table, retrieve it and store in a PHP variable and then use the method in_array on the PHP variable . Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: @hp95  why you are not interested in marking the answer. it's frustrating to help you people. i am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do so

> use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
 $array = (1,2,3,4,5);
 $str = implode(",",$array);
 INSERT INTO `test`(`user_data`) VALUES ($str);
```

or

> use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
 $array = (1,2,3,4,5);
 $json_str= json_encode($array);
 INSERT INTO `test`(`user_data`) VALUES ($json_str);
```

Comment: please verify also as to help others

Comment: json_decode($data,true) returns an associative array